# Looking for the best mega-menu-solution when placed above search-input

Tags: mega-menu

as its written in the subject, im searching for a mega-menu-solution on a site. Given specifications are, that the brand logo itself must stay where it is in size and position and is NOT allowed to be covered.

However the search is allowed to be covered by the menu. 
Also i need a solution where the mega-menu covers the whole width. Otherwise it wouldnt be a challenge ;)

A mockup is attached here: [image: The black square is the brand logo]

Feel free to post ur thoughts and ideas, even if they do not seem to be the the final-solution.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I really don't understand what you need here since your description would be the answer itself. You want to know how to implement it? If so, this is off topic here

Comment: Sorry for my bad english, i edited the subject. The Problem is, that sometimes there is a big image behind the menu, and not just white background. Means: The brand, the menu and the search are directly on that image. Maybe that describes my problem better?

Comment: Why not have the menu below the searchbar?

Answer (score 1):

I see three options:

- Chop a corner out of your full-width mega-menu so it doesn't cover the logo.
- Move your menu bar below the search bar so it can then go full-width below the logo.
- Let the mega-menu cover the logo, but place the logo inside the menu so it's visible when the menu is open.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply and ur thoughts on this. 

- Chopping looks strange - tried that already. 
- If changing placement of search and menu bar would be possible, i would have done that already
- That would work on pages with white background in the header. Tried that too. But on a lot of pages we have background-images that are BEHIND menu bar, search bar and Logo. Therefore it wouldnt work, unless we cover the whole area on top with white.